# net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when accessing Nextjs dev server with Ip address

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

When I run my Nextjs project with `npm run dev`

And access the app with `http://localhost:3000` I saw that the resources was loaded using http protocol, something like: `http://localhost:3000/js/dmak_normal.js`.

But when i try to access it using my ipv4 address `http://123.x.x.x:3000` I saw that the resources was loaded with https protocol like: `https://123.x.x.x:3000/js/dmak_normal.js`.

Thus resulting in net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, especially when accessing it via localhost. But when you want to use another address (http://123.x.x.x:3000 for example) you have to configure ssl connection on server side.
the easiest way to do it - use domain + nginx + Let's Encrypt certificate.
You can find how to do it here https://gist.github.com/kocisov/2a9567eb51b83dfef48efce02ef3ab06